# Windows 8 XAML button is hiding onHover, how can we tackle?

Tags: xaml, button, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Using XAML for mettro app I am getting problem onhover to the button, whenever mouse hovers button turns to hide,

Below is the code of button:

```
<Button x:Name="btnLogin"
        Content="Login"
        Click="btnLogin_click"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="50"
        Margin="83,255,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="114"
        Background="#FFE6410C" />
```

Comment: What's you expected visual state of button when pointer is hovering?

Comment: I don't see this happening at all...the button is still visible to me.  Is there more XAML here that may be affecting it?

Comment: @Xyroid 
I am expecting that on hover it should be still visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the hover effect. You need to customize the button template. Below is the default template, I've commented out `PointerOver` visual state. So there will be no change while pointer hover.

```xml
<Button x:Name="btnLogin"
Content="Login"
Click="btnLogin_click"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Height="50"
Margin="83,255,0,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Width="114"
Background="#FFE6410C" 
Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"/>


<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <!--<Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>-->
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="3">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: thnx xyroid its working fine onhover but facing  same problem onClick it turns hide.

Comment: Then comment out "Pressed" state. Read the whole code first you will get to know all the things.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the XAML that will help you:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Cyan" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Try changing the values.  And do not forget to add the style property in to the button.